# Plotting from 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix which is 1*1*10000, the slightly odd dimensions are the result of the matrix algebra used to calculate it.

I simply want to be able to plot the 10000 data points contained in it, but matlab seems unable to do it?

Can someone please tell me how I can plot the data?

Seems simple but I really can't figure out how to do it!

Baz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you need to reduce the dimensions to a vector:

```
A = zeros(1,1,100)
vector = squeeze(A(1,1,:))
```

as when you'd access the third dimension this would only return a 3D-Matrix again:

```
z = A(1,1,:)
```

would NOT work. So use `squeeze()` ;-) Then plot as usual.

Doc-Link: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html
And as Ander pointed out in comments, no need to give any dimensions, as it removes singleton-dimensions by itself. So just use `vector = squeeze(A)`. MATLAB recognizes the way to go itself.

Comment: or even better vector=squeeze(A)